# How do I import a Google Font with a space in the title in Next.js with @next/font/google?

Tags: next.js, google-fonts

The [Next.js documentation on importing Google Fonts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization#google-fonts) shows this recommended method of importing Google fonts:

```js
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <main className={inter.className}>
      Lorem ipsum dolar set amut
    </main>
  )
}
```

This method works for the `Inter` font and other fonts with single word titles. I'm trying to import a font called [Redacted Script](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Redacted+Script) which has a space in the title.

I tried just TitleCasing it:

```js
import { RedactedScript } from '@next/font/google'
const redactedScript = RedactedScript({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <main className={redactedScript.className}>
      Lorem ipsum dolar set amut
    </main>
  )
}
```

However this code gives me the error:

```
`@next/font` error:
Unknown font `RedactedScript`
```

How do I use `@next/font/google` to import a Google font with a space in it like `Redacted Script`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [a really cool guy at Vercel helping me debug this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45916) I've got the answer: Capital_Snake_Case!

Here's the working code:

```js
import { Redacted_Script } from '@next/font/google'
const redactedScript = Redacted_Script({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <main className={redactedScript.className}>
      Lorem ipsum dolar set amut
    </main>
  )
}
```